# login not activated users in Sentry with laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I am using Sentry 2 in my Laravel project. I have some users that after registering they should activate their users . but I want they can login (even they are not active - confirmed users) and use some features of site. but  I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: i think sentry default doesn't provide that .. see this ..   https://github.com/cartalyst/sentry/issues/273

Comment: thanks, then I should change something in core :) or waiting for version 3 ..